# Juno (eclipse) Open Window Behaviour has changed from previous version. Does anyone know how to restore the old behaviour?

Tags: eclipse

I have side by side editor windows as part of my default development perspective in eclipse in Linux, Windows and Mac versions. On all three platforms, the default behaviour when opening a new class, xml or other editable file was to open it on top of the current active editor. (i.e. if I was editing a file in the right hand editor and opened a type, it would open on the right hand side). Since upgrading(?!) I (and my colleagues) have found that files always open in the left hand side whether or not you are active in the right window or left.

Does anyone have any idea how to restore the old behaviour other than downgrading my eclipse? Having had the original behaviour for so long it is quite annoying to have a completely new behaviour to have to get used to.

I have tried setting my appearance back to classic with no effect. Any other suggestions?